# How to select a column containing an array of values from a subquery in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Given a hypothetical schema of `Manufacturer` and `Model`, is it possible to select all manufacturers with a column containing an array of the model IDs? This would be like the opposite of [UNNEST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), but there is no "**nest**" function.

I've tried:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT md.id FROM model md WHERE md.parent_id = ma.id)
    FROM manufacturer ma;
```

But got the error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was typing the question, I realised the solution was that I was missing the `ARRAY()` constructor:

```
SELECT *, ARRAY(SELECT md.id FROM model md WHERE md.parent_id = ma.id)
    FROM manufacturer ma;
```

From the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS

---

**Edit:** The approach above, while it works, is extremely slow. A much better approach is to join the tables and aggregate them using `ARRAY_AGG()`:

```
SELECT ma.*, ARRAY_AGG(md.id)
    FROM manufacturer ma
    JOIN model md ON md.parent_id = ma.id
    GROUP BY ma.id;
```

`manufacturer.id` must be a primary key to be able to use `ma.*`, but you could group by anything.

In my database, this version took 6 seconds to retrieve 3k rows, while the method above took 67 seconds.